# Is it possible to use @Valid with @HashMap created from JSON payload?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) `@Valid` alongside my `@RequestBody` to validate if my [json](/questions/tagged/json) payload has a given parameter.

I've found solutions that use binding, but to do that is almost like calling the validation within your `@RequestMapping` method. I've also found a way to use `@Valid` when you have a expected Payload.

My payload is completely dynamic and I only want to validate the existence of a field, for example, `id`. My current handler is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/path", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @Valid
    public Object get(final HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @RequestBody HashMap payload ) {
```

Since my payload is completely dynamic I created a `HashMap` to hold it. I was wondering if I could use `@NotEmpty` or a similar annotation if I extend `HashMap` to a custom class that simply verifies if that property exists.

Am I on the right track? Is this not possible for dynamic payloads?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use hibernate validation as well ?

Comment: You can implement the [Validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validator) to ensure your responses are correct.

Comment: @EddieB Validator is one of the options I said I though about, but it does imply the binding and then setting up the validator. I was trying to find a solution by declaration.

Comment: @Amrola no I don't sorry.

Comment: @bitoiu Nope. Don't think so chief... However [Petri](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/) has an awesome walkthrough for REST validation.

Comment: @bitoiu If you're trying to guarantee the 'id' variable you can easily change the 'id' to a parameter as a [path variable](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/25/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-2/)

Comment: @EddieB I will check the tutorial, as for the `id` on the path that would not be a good use of REST in this case as I'm doing a post to create a new resource, id is just an example, I want to validate a given key of the JSON payload. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is yes and no.

**Yes**, you can use `@Valid` for requesting validation.

**No**, you can't use a simple `@NotEmpty` for a property since you would need a defined DTO for that purpose.

Given that the payload is dynamic the best thing I was able to do, was based on @EddieB [tutorial link](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/) and it goes like this.

Same function header as I had in the question

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/path", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object get(final HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @RequestBody HashMap payload ) {
```

But since the payload is dynamic, in this case a HashMap, you need some sort of custom validation. The cleanest way I found was using the `@InitBinder` annotation to attach a `Validator` to that `@Valid` *request*.

```
   // instantiated in the constructor
    private final MyValidator myValidator

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(this.myValidator);
    }
```

And then our custom validator:

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return HashMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       // do your custom validation.
       // if you don't call error.reject* it is considered a valid argument
    }
```

If you did throw an error, you catch it by creating a `@ControllerAdvice`. In my case I explicitly set the `@ResponseStatus` to `BAD_REQUEST` as if it gets here, it is definitely caused by a bad payload:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        // custom error handling
    }
}
```

Thanks to both members for the comments that led me to this answer.

Comment: Hello,  I know it's a old question, do HashMap.class should mention in support method?